# C++ Boost: How To Run boost_check_library.py

Tags: c++, testing, boost, bjam

I'm trying to run `<boost>/status/boost_check_library.py` for a particular Boost library to test that it conforms to the Boost Library Requirements.

However, I'm having a hard time finding how to do so - there does not appear to be any documentation on the subject. I found that it's meant to be executed from `<boost>/status/Jamfile.v2`, but my knowledge of jamfiles is limited and I can't seem to get it to work.

Would anyone have any experience with this and be willing to help? Thank you! :)

Comment: Do you have python installed? In fact, what is your problem specifically? What did you try? How did it fail? SO is not a tech support resource.

Comment: Check your python installation by typing python -v on a terminal. If you don't, get python and then run the script on the terminal by 'python boost_check_library.py'

Comment: Apologies! I have Python installed (version 2.7). The problem lies in finding the correct combination of command-line options to execute the test script. Perhaps a better question would be... Is there any known way to run it? ^^ I'm in the process of perusing the code in investigation, but it's strange how nothing on the internet shows how the script may be used.

Comment: Nothing shows how to run it because it's a really new script I wrote.. And because it's mostly an internal script that is usually only used from b2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have managed to find a solution :)

Predonditions:

- You're using Python 2.7

To run all tests for a library, you can use:

`./boost_check_library.py --boost-root=".." --library="libs/<library>/" --jamfile="Jamfile.v2" --debug organization organization-build organization-doc organization-include organization-meta organization-test`

Where `<library>` the library that you want to test.

Hope this helps someone ^_^

Comment: You can shorten that command to only include the "organization" check. As it will include all the sub-checks (organization-*) in that case. Otherwise, that's the direct way to use it. It's also possible to just do: b2 --check-libs-only --limit-tests=<library>

Comment: Oh! Thank you :) I did not find the `--check-libs-only` option documented anywhere.